# Inconsistent annotation for 'WinMain'

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, code-analysis

I'm trying to get my code as perfect as possible, and I've cleaned up all errors and (other) warnings. I'm left with these two:

```
Warning C28253  Inconsistent annotation for 'WinMain': _Param_(2) has 'SAL_null(__no)' on this instance.
Warning C28252  Inconsistent annotation for 'WinMain': _Param_(2) has 'SAL_null(__maybe)' on the prior instance.
```

Here is my WinMain function

```
int CALLBACK WinMain( _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow );
```

Why is my second paramater `HINSTANCE hPrevInstance` not annotated correctly despite it being ripped straight from MSDN with the `_In_` info?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is because the `hPrevInstance` argument actually has the `_In_opt_`  annotation rather than just `_In_`.

Comment: MSDN fails me again D:

Comment: I ended up looking at the declaration in winbase.h to make sure I got it right, I knew it was optional (and in fact in win32 and win64 hPrevInstance will always be null) but wasn't sure of the exact annotation.

Comment: Luckily, the MSDN no longer shows [*any* SAL annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-winmain), so at least it won't show the wrong ones. Now it just claims it were using the `__clrcall` calling convention. Sigh. The amount of damage that .NET has done to Windows as a native developer platform is far beyond apprehension.