# Issues running WinMain in C

Tags: c, visual-studio, winmain

Currently I'm having issues with `WinMain` in C (specifically in Visual Studio).

For instance...

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <Windows.h>

int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
    PSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow)
{

    return(0);
}

1>------ Build started: Project: GameB, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>LIBCMTD.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)
1>E:\James\VisualStudio\CProjects\GameB\x64\Debug\GameB.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "GameB.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Just this basic set-up gives me an "inconsistent annotation for WinMain" warning.  I have been searching for any help for 2 days and the the closest I come to an answer is people talking about WinMain in the context of C++. I have a feeling this is a problem with Visual Studio as I was originally just using VS Code and managed to get an app (one that generated a pop-up window) to compile and run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the `WinMain` program entry point, you need to tell the linker to target the "Windows" subsystem, rather than building a console application. Otherwise, the linker will look for (and fail to find) the standard `main` entry point for C programs.

In the Solution Explorer, right-click on your project and select "Properties". Then navigate to the "Linker -> System" page and select "Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)" as the target:

[image]

On your "inconsistent annotation" warning, see this Q/A: [Inconsistent annotation for 'WinMain'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47958366/10871073)

---

Also, as noted [in the answer by SNO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72622733/10871073), you should add the `WINAPI` attribute to your `WinMain` function.

Answer (score 1):

You just set up your winmain wrong. This should work:

```
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
```

or

```
INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    PSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow)
{
    return 0;
}
```

**Don't forget to #include <Windows.h> and change subsystem to windows.**

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter which way I write the function it still gives me warning. In my original code I had windows.h instead of Windows.h but even changing that still results in the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set subsystem from `Console` to `Windows` in settings, by right clicking your project in the solution explorer, selecting `properties`, and going to `Linker->System` and setting `SubSystem` to `Windows(/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)`.