# WinMain taken from docs can't be compiled

Tags: c++, windows, msdn, winmain, sal

I have the following declaration of WinMain.

```cpp
int CALLBACK WinMain(
  HINSTANCE hInstance,
  HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  LPSTR lpCmdLine,
  int nShowCmd
)
```

This compiles, however it generates the following warning.

```
Warning C28251 Inconsistent annotation for 'WinMain': this instance has no annotations
```

I tried to specify input / output attributes like this.

```cpp
int CALLBACK WinMain(
  _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
  _In_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine,
  _In_ int nShowCmd
)
```

That didn't help so I changed the attribute for `hPrevInstance` as suggested by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47958431/10732434).

```cpp
int CALLBACK WinMain(
  _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
  _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine,
  _In_ int nShowCmd
)
```

That didn't help so I looked at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-winmain) which uses `in` as an attribute. So I changed the declaration once again.

```cpp
int CALLBACK WinMain(
  in HINSTANCE hInstance,
  in HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  in LPSTR lpCmdLine,
  in int nShowCmd
)
```

But guess what. I got an error this time.

```
C2065 'in': undeclared identifier
```

Here is an example file.

```
#include <sb7/sb7.h>

struct App : public sb7::application {
    void render(const double time) {
        GLfloat color[] = { 1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f };
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, color);
    }
};

DECLARE_MAIN(App);
```

The sb7 library is taken from [GitHub](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb7code). The WinMain declaration is located in the library source code.

The MSVC version is 193431937.

How do I remove the warning about inconsistent annotations and compile WinMain successfully?

Comment: Can you post the whole file that you're trying to compile, plus the version of MSVC that you're on?

Comment: As you say, it's only a warning, and you can safely disable it with `#pragma warning (disable : 28251)`.  But, that said, I don't know why you're getting it.  I don't include any annotations (they're a SAL thing) and I don't.  One thing though: `WinMain` is supposed to be declared `APIENTRY`, not `CALLBACK`.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Absolutely.

Comment: @PaulSanders It doesn't matter what I choose. In the end, all are expanded into `__stdcall`.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica After I restarted Visual Studio the warning magically disappeared.